# Styleguide settings for Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I've started to use Koltin heavily and struggling a bit with code formatting.

Although there is an official [coding conventions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) guide, but I wonder if there is any public available styleguide settings for IntelliJ (such as [google codestyle](https://github.com/google/styleguide) for Java) which you can grab/import and use?

Comment: https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an official Kotlin style guide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206515/is-there-an-official-kotlin-style-guide)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [Is there an official Kotlin style guide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206515/is-there-an-official-kotlin-style-guide).  This question isn't for conventions, it is for importable IntelliJ settings.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to grab/import them they are built into IntelliJ IDEA's Kotlin language support plugin.

You can reformat Kotlin source code just like you would code written in Java or other supported languages.

From [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 Help :: Reformatting Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformatting-source-code.html):

> ### Basics
>
> IntelliJ IDEA lets you reformat source code to meet the requirements
>   of your code style. IntelliJ IDEA will lay out spacing, indents,
>   keywords etc. Reformatting can apply to the selected text, entire
>   file, or entire project.
>
> It is also possible to apply reformatting to the parts of the source
>   code only, using the [formatting markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-style.html#formatter_options).
>
> ### Reformatting code
>
> To reformat code for a directory, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the Project tool window, select a module or directory you want to
>      apply your reformatting to.
> 2. From the main menu, select **Code | Reformat
>      Code** or press `Ctrl+Alt+L`.
>
>    Alternatively, in the [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/project-tool-window.html),
>      right-click the directory and from the context menu, select **Reformat
>      Code**.
> 3. In the [Reformat Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformat-code-on-directory-dialog.html) dialog box, specify the necessary options
>      and filters for you reformatting and click **Run**.
>
> ### Reformatting code for the current file
>
> To reformat code for the current file, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the editor of the currently opened file, press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L`.
>
>    Note that if you select **Code | Reformat Code** from the main menu or
>      press `Ctrl+Alt+L`, IntelliJ IDEA will try to reformat the source code
>      automatically without opening the [Reformat File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformat-file-dialog.html) dialog.
> 2. In the [Reformat File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformat-file-dialog.html) dialog, specify options for the reformatting and click
>      Run.

Comment: The settings I had didn't follow the conventions spelled out [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html), so reformatting did nothing useful.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (November 3nd, 2017), there's also the [official Kotlin style guide for Android](https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html) maintained by Google.

It doesn't have a plugin yet, but there is an issue [Evaluate providing IntelliJ code style configuration](https://github.com/android/kotlin-guides/issues/2) which (I guess) will be solved in the nearest future.

Answer (score 0):

There is discussion on Official Kotlin page: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/official-kotlin-style-guide/213/5

The most interesting part of it is @yole answer:

> Yes, IntelliJ IDEA *does have a built-in formatter* for Kotlin code, and
>   we plan to *improve it significantly* before the release. We do not have
>   any plans to provide any kind of tool that would complain about
>   "incorrect" formatting, for any definition of "incorrect".

Of course, as @IRUS noticed there's also an Github repo, where you can report any issue or problem with Kotlin coding style.

Just follow: https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide

This might be also handful: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-style.html

Hope it will help